# insert multi data in js, on databases

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, post

I tried to create a web app in JS to make multiple reservations at same time.
I've builded this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var prezzo = Number(6.50).toFixed(2);
</script>

    <a href="#">POSTO 1</a> <span style="display: inline-block;" id="p1"></span>  <button onclick="this.style.visibility='hidden'; fp1();">PRENOTA</button> <br>
    <a href="#">POSTO 2</a> <span style="display: inline-block;" id="p2"></span>  <button id="bp2" onclick="fp2();">PRENOTA</button> <br>
    <a href="#">POSTO 3</a> <br>
    <a href="#">POSTO 4</a> <br>



</body>

<script>
function fp1() {

  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo Nome" id="nome">' + '<input type="text" name="cognome" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo Cognome" id="cognome">'  + prezzo + " " + "€" + " " +'<button id="invia" onclick="invia()" class="btn">INVIA</button>';

  
}

function fp2() {

  document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo Nome" id="nome">' + '<input type="text" name="cognome" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo Cognome" id="cognome">'  + prezzo + " " + "€" + " " +'<button id="invia2" onclick="invia()" class="btn">INVIA</button>';

    document.getElementById("bp2").style.visibility='hidden'; 
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">function invia()
 {
    var nome = document.getElementById('nome').value;
    var cognome = document.getElementById('cognome').value;
    
   {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "insert.php",
          data: {"cognome": cognome, "nome":nome, "prezzo":prezzo},
          success: function(data){
            console.log(nome);
          },

          error: function(data) {
            console.log("Dati non inviati");
          }
      });
    }
```

*The problem is that when I try to insert data on db, the function don't take the correct values, but just the first inserted.*

Comment: and where is your backend code?

Comment: BE code it's just an insert to db, and it's work fine.

//$id = $_POST['id'];
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$cognome = $_POST['cognome'];
$prezzo = $_POST['prezzo'];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO assegnazioneposti (nome, cognome, prezzo)
  VALUES ('$nome', '$cognome', '$prezzo')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
 etc...